# using rosdistro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to use rosdistro install it or use it ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42495/using-rosdistro/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-08-28**:
What are you trying to do with rosdistro?

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-28**:
i want to install these https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/rosdistro/tree/acd0dbcb697678723c10e0daba62daced755d057

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-28**:
i want to install these https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/rosdistro/tree/acd0dbcb697678723c10e0daba62daced755d057

**Comment by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on 2012-08-28**:
because i have micro card and atom board i have to install these thing off line and move them to the micro sd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdistro is part of rospkg. If you have added the ROS sources, you can install it using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
```

You can also install it from source:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/ros/rospkg.git 
$ python setup.py install --user
```

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0